# nohup to run .sh file

Tags: batch-processing, argv, nohup

I use nohup to run run.sh file. There are many .inp files in the same folder as run.sh, so I use the following command to run all the cases.

```css
nohup bash run.sh *.inp > nohup.out&
```

The run.sh file is

```css
#!/bin/tcsh -f
@ n = $#argv
```

But I get an error in run.sh file saying @: command not found. I am wondering if $#argv means the name of all the input file? What is the mistake then?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: wait, youre using bash to launch a tcsh script?

Comment: Yes. I tried ./run.sh but failed with 'No such file or directory'. So I changed to bash as in the question. It can run but got the error. What's the problem to use bash? What should I do?